# Temporarily unzip a file to view contents within a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jszip

I want to unzip a file that contains an html page, css, and js directories. I want to unzip this temporarily and view the html in an iFrame, preferrably. I am using jszip which is working. I got the html to load, but how do I add the image, js, and css folders into the iFrame?

Here is what I have so far...

```
<div id="jszip_utils"></div>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showError(elt, err) {
        elt.innerHTML = "<p class='alert alert-danger'>" + err + "</p>";
    }
    function showContent(elt, content) {
        elt.innerHTML = "<p class='alert alert-success'>loaded !<br/>" +
          "Content = " + content + "</p>";
    }
    var htmltext = JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("/zip/myWebsite.zip", function (err, data) {
        var elt = document.getElementById('jszip_utils');
        if (err) {
            showError(elt, err);
            return;
        }
        try {
            JSZip.loadAsync(data)
                .then(function (zip) {
                    for(var name in zip.files) {
                        if (name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) === "html") {
                            return zip.file(name).async("string");
                        }
                    }
                    return zip.file("").async("string");
                })
                .then(function success(text) {
                    $('#iframe').contents().find('html').html(text);
                    showContent(elt, text);
                }, function error(e) {
                    showError(elt, e);
                });
        } catch(e) {
            showError(elt, e);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This gets the html, but the js css and image files are not showing up. I believe I need to do some sort of fake routing, but I'm not sure how I would be able to do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pretty difficult. The only widely-supported way is to use a server or have the user manually download, unzip, and open the HTML page. Until recently that was the only option. If you're willing to limit compatibility, you could now use [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: What you can try is: create a temporary folder in the root of your site. Unzip all the files there. Point the iframe to open www.mysite.com/temporary-folder. Untested and may require page to be reloaded. It goes without saying that you need to trust users on what they are uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the html/js in the zip is not too complicated, for instance an AngularJS app that has routes for partials, this is possible.

The trick is to replace css,js,img src/href urls that point to a file in the zip with either:

- [Object Url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL): URL.createObjectURL(Blob or File object);
- [Data Url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs): `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`
- Or in the case of js and css inject the content directly into the appropriate element

After replacing the src/href references than just inject the new html into the iframe.

Step 1: Parse the html so you can manipulate it

```
//html from a call like zip.file("index.html").async("string")
let parser = new DOMParser;
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html,"text/html");
```

Step 2: Find all elements with a relative path (e.g. */imgs/img.jpg*) as they are easier to deal with as you can then use that path for zip.file

```
//Simply finds all resource elements, then filters all that dont start with '/'
var elements = jQuery("link[href],script[src],img[src]",doc).filter(function(){
   return /^\//.test(this.href || this.src);
});
```

Step 3: Replace src,href with object url, data url, or direct content

```
//assume element is the html element: <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
zip.file(element.src).async("string").then(jsText=>{
   element.src = "data:text/javascript,"+encodeURIComponent(jsText);
});
```

Step 4: Get the new html text and inject it into the iframe

```
let newHTML = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
var viewer = document.querySelector('#iframeID');
viewer = viewer.contentWindow || viewer.contentDocument.document || viewer.contentDocument;

viewer.document.open();
viewer.document.write(html);
viewer.document.close();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1p8neg41/1/) - Demonstrates replacing the src/href urls

As a security note, if you are using zip files that you do not know the contents of, you should run the whole app in a protected iframe

Comment: I found this answer but still Im trying to figure out how to solve my problem, Is it possible to read *.json file inside *.tgz file through the browser ?

Comment: @Bozinovski yes just do the same `async("string")` part and do `JSON.parse(jsText)` in the `then(...)` callback instead of doing the `element.src = ...` part