# Is there a way to download a file in JavaScript and write it to the body as base64

Tags: javascript, url, download, base64, zip

Is there a way to do the following in vanilla JS:

1. Download file from URL
2. Base64 encode it
3. Write the data to the body

Oh and also this will have to be run client side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporarily unzip a file to view contents within a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075591/temporarily-unzip-a-file-to-view-contents-within-a-browser)

Comment: These questions have all been answered. But you'll have to search for each of them individually. Break your problem down and try solving a step at a time. On Base64 encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370943/retrieving-binary-file-content-using-javascript-base64-encode-it-and-reverse-de On Unzipping/dealing with files in the browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075591/temporarily-unzip-a-file-to-view-contents-within-a-browser

Comment: Yeah but how can I download files in pure JS, all the solutions I have found don't work in my specific use case

Comment: The zip tag appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: use object urls instead of base64

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let f = new FileReader();
f.onload = () => {
    document.body.append(document.createTextNode(f.result.split(",")[1]))
};
fetch("Your URL").then(r=>r.blob()).then(r=>f.readAsDataURL(r))
```

It downloads the file using the `fetch` API, then uses a `FileReader` to get a base64 data URL. The data URL is then split, and only the base64 data is kept. A text node containing the base64 text is then appended to the `body`.