# Rendering a ZIP-compressed SPA with JS

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, webassembly

Thank you for browsing.

I have a small **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplication that is compressed into a ZIP file.
It consists of an HTML file, other JS files and CSS.

I would like to create a sandbox space (e.g., iframe, etc.) in my browser and render this zip file there without a server, is this technically possible?

I know there is an option to temporarily host it on the server side, but any ideas on how to complete it on the front end only?

If there is any information that I am missing, please ask.

Thanks for reading to the end.

---

### Supplement 1

The ZIP file will be hosted by S3.

We expect to be able to use libraries such as zlib.js to decompress the files. The following is a sample directory structure.

```
- test.zip
  - index.html
  - abc.js
  - def.js
  - images/
    - a.png
    - b.png
```

`index.html` will load various JS files and image files with relative paths.

---

### Duplicated

[Temporarily unzip a file to view contents within a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075591/temporarily-unzip-a-file-to-view-contents-within-a-browser)
Thanks to [@BenRondeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4674232/ben-rondeau)

Comment: How would you host the zip file? And how would the file be unzipped?

Comment: Thanks for reading, I've added it to the question.

Comment: Since the files is in a ZIP, you will need to unzip it before a browser can read the source files (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.). I don't believe this is a capability of an S3 bucket so you will need a server to unzip the files.

Comment: That's usually the case, and I know I have that option. Is it technically impossible to unzip and render the contents in a browser?

Comment: Have you noticed this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075591/temporarily-unzip-a-file-to-view-contents-within-a-browser 

Unless you have a strong reason for delivering files this way (zipped), I would recommend another approach as this is very uncommon and is likely unreliable.

Comment: Thank you!!! This question is extremely close to mine. I hadn't noticed. I am aware that it is not reliable.
I will check this question.

Comment: Sure. Hope you find the answer you are looking for!

Comment: Any space saving you have here by zipping your files are going to be negated by having to ship zip.js (or similar). I'd suggest using gzip compression instead, which is natively and transparently decompressed by browsers without any additional JS libraries and works with S3 with [a little trick](https://medium.com/@graysonhicks/how-to-serve-gzipped-js-and-css-from-aws-s3-211b1e86d1cd).

Comment: Service workers?